# Error while using jar file in android studio

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am doing one project in that i want to use jar file. Actually I converted .apk file to .jar file by using dex2jar. I added that .jar file in lib folder and added as library. but when running the app it shows an error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

and my build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.protocolnet.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/viabee-dex2jar.jar')
}
```

.
How to get rid from that error. Please anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .jar file converted from apk as a Library because of that it is not Library. You can get source code using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file.).

Comment: thank u. I got source code from that method. But when I importing that project into android studio it asking import project from external model if I select that what will be the gradle location how to select that?

Comment: If that is a gradle project select project main path. There must be a build.gradle file.

Comment: I only created build.gradle file. Is that fine? If I want to use that code in my project when a button is clicked then what to do?

Comment: Find the source code that button onClick listener. Copy and paste to your onClickListener.